# Adding Drawable to Android library project

Tags: android

When I place ic_sam.png in drawables of module project which my main app includes, while getting that drawable R.drawable.ic_sam below is the error
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:

Is that we cannot add the drawables in to library projects?

If no than where to add ? experts please guide.

Answer (score 2):

You have to create an `AAR` project if you want to bundle resources with your library. More help in how to create the `aar` project can be found out [here](https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/02/23/building-an-aar-library-in-android-studio/)

Comment: Thanks for responding . i believe i have done that , still the error is same.